# How to Get info about phone calls

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, callkit

I have to develop a mobile application that monitors some info about calls, to limit users of a company to spend too much time with the phone near their ears. After *x* minutes, it should suggest to use earphones.

1st question: is it possible to monitor data like this? Phonecall time duration, start and end, if it's using earphones, internal or external speaker.. I mean, without using jailbreak or other hackings.

2nd question: is it possible doing this for IOS and Android?

3rt question: Do you know if Ionic has the capability to that?

Thank you.

Comment: is my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Android:**

- You can easily get the call history or incoming and outgoing call time.
  So it is possible in android.

**For iOS:**

According to your question you want to limit the current calling time of phone near their ears.

So you also do it in iOS by some smartness.

- In iOS 10 a new framework introduces for calling i.e. CallKit.
- First, you have to get all contact in your application.
- So user should call from your app.
- For dialing also add the custom phone dialer.

By Some method of callKit you can do:

1. Add a call observer

   @property ( nonatomic ) CXCallObserver *callObserver;
2. Initialize the call observer:

   - (instancetype)init
     {
         self = [super init];
         if (self) {

     ```
         //Initialize the call observer
         _callObserver = [CXCallObserver new];
         [_callObserver setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
     }
     return self;
     ```

     }

Add the delegate of call kit

```
#pragma mark - CXCallObserverDelegate
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call{
    [self callStateValue:call];
}

#pragma mark - Callkit State
- (void)callStateValue:(CXCall *)call {

    NSLog(@"Call UIID: %@", call.UUID);
    NSLog(@"hasEnded     %@", call.hasEnded? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"isOutgoing   %@", call.isOutgoing? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"isOnHold     %@", call.isOnHold? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"hasConnected %@", call.hasConnected? @"YES":@"NO");

    if (call == nil || call.hasEnded == YES) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Disconnected");
        [timer1 invalidate];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.duration);
        if(self.duration>1)
        self.duration=1;
    }

    if (call.isOutgoing == YES && call.hasConnected == NO) {
    }

    if (call.isOutgoing == NO  && call.hasConnected == NO && call.hasEnded == NO && call != nil) {
        self.duration = 0;
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Incoming");
        NSLog(@"Call Details: %@",call);
    }

    if (call.hasConnected == YES && call.hasEnded == NO) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallState : Connected");
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        self.duration++;
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.duration);
    }];

    }
}
```

You can get the time duration and also add the condition After x minutes, it should suggest to use earphones.

Comment: Looking into something like this and was wondering if it would it be possible to also find out who hung up the call?

Answer (score 2):

**Answering your questions:**

**Question1:** Yes it's possible on Android. It's not possible on iOS. In Android, you can get call information if the user permits. You don't need to do jailbreaking or something. Whereas in iOS no way you can access call info.

**Question2:** Hope my first answer itself answers this. i.,e Android-Possible, iOS- not Possible

**Question 3:** AFAIK ionic framework is providing only basic details of Phone call time duration and contacts framework. You should explore more on Android to find out. Even if you use ionic framework you can't access this info at all on iPhone as native ios only not providing these details, we can't expect this from ionic framework.

Comment: I see on the market (also for IOS) many apps that say to monitor (or spy) phone usage, incoming and outgoing calls, etc..    they are a sort of fake?  I've never used them actually.

Comment: No it's not possible. May be they are doing it for marketing. At final they will mention a note saying these features works with jailbreaking devices.